# Build a Make based C++ project using Android NDK

Tags: makefile, android-ndk, ndk-build

I need to build [csparse library](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) for an Android project. The project supports Make build system.

I am not familiar with use of NDK for **Make build**. I have used Androids **CMake toolchain** for building CMake based projects.

I am looking for pointers to usage of NDK for building C++ projects based on Make. I do not want to manually write a CMakeLists.txt for building the project with CMake toolchain because there are too many source files in the csparse project!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems covers using the NDK with build systems other than ndk-build and CMake. The [last section](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems#non-autoconf_make_projects) explicitly covers traditional make projects.

Answer (score 0):

OK, It wasn't so difficult. It seems CSparse is a self-contained and does not depend on other linear-algebra libraries such as CHOLMOD, BLAS, LAPACK, Metis... etc

Here is the CMakeLists.txt file from my Android project :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
include_directories(
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/CSparse/Source
)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        csparse-lib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_add.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_amd.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_chol.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_cholsol.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_compress.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_counts.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_cumsum.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_dfs.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_dmperm.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_droptol.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_dropzeros.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_dupl.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_entry.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_ereach.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_etree.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_fkeep.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_gaxpy.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_happly.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_house.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_ipvec.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_leaf.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_load.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_lsolve.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_ltsolve.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_lu.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_lusol.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_malloc.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_maxtrans.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_multiply.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_norm.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_permute.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_pinv.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_post.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_print.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_pvec.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_qr.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_qrsol.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_randperm.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_reach.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_scatter.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_scc.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_schol.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_spsolve.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_sqr.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_symperm.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_tdfs.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_transpose.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_updown.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_usolve.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_util.c
        include/CSparse/Source/cs_utsolve.c
        )


add_library(native-lib SHARED native-lib.cpp)



find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        log)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib

        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib}

        csparse-lib
        )
```

I hope this answer helps others.